# Jenkins + GitLab CI Pipeline Maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am having a Maven project and I am trying to create a CI pipeline using Jenkins for releasing the project on the commit/merge request. Able to successfully release the new version but stuck in looping issue.

**Steps:**

- Create Jenkinsfile in the project.
- Create pipeline project in Jenkins.
- Enable Webhook in GitLab -> integration.
- Push the code from local machine by developer to GitLab repo with version as 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
- Pipeline triggered automatically, since webhook is enabled.
- Maven build and test run successfully.
- Maven Release prepare and perform with "ci skip as commit prefix" is committing to GitLab repo with version as 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT (Next Version).
- Again Pipeline triggered, since new commit has been pushed.

As of now in Jenkins, I am checking the commit message contains skip ci and skipping the staging. Because of this for every single commit two time pipeline is triggered.

In Azure Pipeline we are able to stop the looping by giving `***NO_CI***`.

Could you please suggest a best way to handle this in Jenkins pipeline or in GitLab webhook?

Answer (score 0):

See [Builds by source changes](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-Buildsbysourcechanges):

> Alternatively, instead of polling on a fixed interval, you can use a URL trigger (described above), but with `/polling` instead of `/build` at the end of the URL. This makes Jenkins poll the SCM for changes rather than building immediately. This prevents Jenkins from running a build with no relevant changes for commits affecting modules or branches that are unrelated to the job. When using /polling the job must be configured for polling, but the schedule can be empty.

**Pipeline** → Definition: *Pipeline Script from SCM* → SCM → Additional Behaviours → <kbd>Add</kbd> → **Polling ignores commits with certain messages** → [image] :

> If set, and Jenkins is set to poll for changes, Jenkins will ignore any revisions committed with message matched to Pattern when determining if a build needs to be triggered. **This can be used to exclude commits done by the build itself from triggering another build**, assuming the build server commits the change with a distinct message.

[Emphasis by me.]

Disclaimer: Not tested in real, just RTFM.